# Add comments to cell from another cell, if the source cell in blank or zero, skip the cell and go to next

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple spreadsheet, I want to copy the comments from the source column (C3:C10) to the target column (A3:A10) on a per cell basis . Example: Comments from cell C3 need to be a comment on A3 , C4 on A4, C5 on A5.. but no comment on cell A6 because C6 is blank or zero, then C7 on A7 and so on..

Below is the code that I got and  I always got an error on (.Text Text:=Target(i).Value) because cell C6 and C10 are blank.

Please help to rewrite the code below, to skip the blank cell and go to the next... Thank you

```
Sub Comments()

    Range("A3:A10").Select
    Selection.ClearComments


    Dim Target As Range, Source As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cm As Comment, i As Integer
    Set Source = Range("a3:a10")
    Set Target = Range("c3:c10")

    For Each rng In Source
        i = i + 1
        If Not rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
            rng.Comment.Delete
        End If
        Set cm = rng.AddComment
        With cm
            .Visible = False
            .Text Text:=Target(i).Value  '<===== got an error on this**
        End With
    Next rng
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. Instead of looping through each cell it just copies the comments from one range to the other and then deletes the comments at source.

```
Sub Comments()

    Dim Target As Range, Source As Range
    Dim Tmp As Variant

    Set Source = Range("c3:c10")
    Set Target = Range("a3:a10")

    Tmp = Target.Value
    Source.Copy
    Target.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments, _
                                 Operation:=xlNone, _
                                 SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                 Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Source.ClearComments
    Source.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

`SpecialCells()` method to filter cells with values only

`Offset(rowOffset, colOffset)` method to shift between your "parallel" ranges

```
Option Explicit

Sub Comments()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Range("A3:A10")
        .ClearComments
        For Each rng In .Offset(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, -2)
            With rng.AddComment
                .Visible = False
                .Text Text:=rng.Offset(, 2).Value
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you are welcome. you may want to choose the best answer for you and mark it as accepted and help people who will stumble upon this topic

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You are not checking if the cell is empty.

```
Sub Comments()

Dim Target As Range, Source As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cm As Comment, i As Integer

Set Source = Range("a3:a10")
Set Target = Range("c3:c10")

Source.ClearComments

For Each rng In Source
    i = i + 1
    If Target(i).Value <> vbNullString Then
        Set cm = rng.AddComment
        With cm
            .Text Target(i).Value
            .Visible = False
        End With
    End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helps

Answer (score 0):

Here I recommend you a better way, you don't need to consider the blank cells. It will ignore automatically. Enjoy it. I think that is what you exactly need.

```
Sub addcomment()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
        Cells(i, 1).NoteText Cells(i, 3)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To Make it clear, here I add a picture.
[image]

Comment: Hello @Anabas, I don't understand how this works. If i try to evaluate the up-bound part of the loop shouldn't I get: Cells(9,1).End(3).Row ... 
 Cells(9,3).Row ...  9  --> For i=3 To 9 ? I may be missing something about the End property used with an Integer argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right.`Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row` can also be written as `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. It always finds the last cell used automatically, then we can extend our range dynamically.